# is it possible for me to update database with data gotten from ajax GET REQUEST in my laravel controller without further ajax request on success?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to Update users table after PAYSTACK payment is successful using an AJAX GET REQUEST inside the laravel controller using data gotten from the ajax request. You can go straight to the controller code which is where i am having issues...

Payment Form and Ajax is working very well:

```
 <form id="paymentForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label> <br>
    <input type="email" id="email-address" required />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="amount">Amount</label><br>
    <input type="tel" id="amount" required />
  </div>

  <div class="form-submit">
    <button type="submit" onclick="payWithPaystack(event)"> Pay </button>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://js.paystack.co/v1/inline.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
const paymentForm = document.getElementById('paymentForm');
paymentForm.addEventListener("submit", payWithPaystack, false);
function payWithPaystack(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let handler = PaystackPop.setup({
    key: 'pk_test_058624cb23f26e6f1a75325ec7cdc84ead42b999', // Replace with your public key
    email: document.getElementById("email-address").value,
    amount: document.getElementById("amount").value * 100,
    ref: ''+Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1), // generates a pseudo-unique reference. Please replace with a reference you generated. Or remove the line entirely so our API will generate one for you
    // label: "Optional string that replaces customer email"
    onClose: function(){
      alert('Window closed.');
    },
    callback: function(response){

      let reference = response.reference;

      // verify pay
      $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "{{URL::to('verify-payment')}}/"+reference,

         success: function(response){
            console.log(response);
         }
      });
    }
  });
  handler.openIframe();
}
</script>
```

Ajax Get route in Web.php:

```
Route::get('verify-payment/{reference}', 'UsersController@verify_pay')->name('verify-payment');
```

This is where i am having issues in controller:

```
public function verify_pay($reference)
    {
        $sec = "sk_test_1ee78b7e4524cf19d3450e198812d1b8f0ee6562";
        $curl = curl_init();
  
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.paystack.co/transaction/verify/$reference",
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
          CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Bearer $sec",
            "Cache-Control: no-cache",
          ),
        ));
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $newData = json_decode($response);
        $u_input = [];

        if ([$newData][0]->status == true) {
            $ff = [[$newData][0]->data->amount];
            $up_input["donation_sum"] = strval($ff[0]/100); This line is not running Nor the Line Below
            $up_input["donation_sum"] = $ff[0]/100; This line is not running
            Auth::User()->update($u_input);
            return "paid";
        }else {
            return "something went wrong";
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: i had to elaborate it for any one to get my point but my problem is in the controller. below lines in particular:::       $up_input["donation_sum"] = strval($ff[0]/100); This line is not running Nor the Line Below
            $up_input["donation_sum"] = $ff[0]/100; This line is not running
            Auth::User()->update($u_input);

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69730371/edit) your question to add clarification/information to your question instead of in comments.

Comment: Debug your response and be sure of your status. I have a doubt on `[$newData][0]->status`, should be `$newData->status` no ?

Comment: I got my response very well, what I don't understand is why the update query is not running. Could it be because of the preventDefault() functionality in jQuery?.  I have tried $newData->status but it's throwing an error....

Comment: Please provide error information.

Comment: With my current code, it doesn't create any error I am still getting the ajax returned information on success. My problem is the update functionality is not being effective. Does ajax GET prevent all db functionalities?

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, I only added csrf token and use single $input['donation_sum'] instead of double $input["donation_sum"].